# Routing with parametrs in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-routing

I've got problems with my routing configuration. My app logic - I've got a dropdown in header which controls navigation. Dropdown options navigate to page with extra navigation bar under dropdown. Routing parameter is passing when you click on dropdown option. Problem is that I need to load component which isn't on navigation bar, but used as default screen after dropdown navigation.

First navigation "layer" is dropdown. After that URL is **index/Param#**.

Second navigation "layer" is nav bar, which loaded on pages with url **index/Param#**. On that pages I've got component ("default screen"), which loaded when url is **index/Param#**. But this component doesn't have any links on nav bar.

When I click links on navbar url becomes **index/Param#/params** or **index/Param#/results** etc.
[My app logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztxFs.jpg)

App-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', component: MainComponent },
   { path: 'stages', component: StagesComponent }
];
```

Stages-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'stages', component: StagesComponent, children: [
    { path: ':name', component: StageComponent },
    { path: 'programm', component: ProgrammComponent },
    { path: 'jury', component: JuryComponent },
    { path: 'finalists', component: FinalistsComponent },
    { path: 'results', component: ResultsComponent },
    { path: 'photo', component: PhotoComponent },
    { path: 'partners', component: PartnersComponent },
    { path: 'contacts', component: ContactsComponent},
    ]}
];
```

myService.ts

```
navigateTo(selectedItem) {
      this.router.navigate(['stages', selectedItem]);
     // selectedItem is dropdown value
  }
```

When I navigate for example to "programm" Angular can't resolve this path. What should I do?

Comment: Missing ``\`` after stages in `navigateTo()` function?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: try: `this.router.navigate(['/stages/', selectedItem]);`

Answer (score 0):

Add `/` after `stages` will solve your problem.

```
navigateTo(selectedItem) {
      this.router.navigate(['stages/', selectedItem]);
     // selectedItem is dropdown value
  }
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

basically what you've did here is all routes goes to `stages/:name` and other routes bellow them is never accessed and you have to delete just this line 
`{ path: ':name', component: StageComponent }`
 and everything will work fine as you expected

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'stages', component: StagesComponent, children: [
    { path: ':name', component: StageComponent }, // Delete this line
    { path: 'programm', component: ProgrammComponent },
    { path: 'jury', component: JuryComponent },
    { path: 'finalists', component: FinalistsComponent },
    { path: 'results', component: ResultsComponent },
    { path: 'photo', component: PhotoComponent },
    { path: 'partners', component: PartnersComponent },
    { path: 'contacts', component: ContactsComponent},
    ]}
];
```

Error here is Angular routes is reading from top to bottom and first child routes expected a param `name` and everything what goes after `stages/whatever` will render `StagesComponent` and other routes is never touched.

You can add this line of code at the end of childrend array this mean first it will chec if is

```
'stages/programm' if isn't this route go to next one
'stages/jury' if isn't this route go to next one 
...
// and so one till the end of array
// and if no child routes find then will display default component which is 'StageComponent' 

// so your routes array should be something like this
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'stages', component: StagesComponent, children: [
    { path: 'programm', component: ProgrammComponent },
    { path: 'jury', component: JuryComponent },
    { path: 'finalists', component: FinalistsComponent },
    { path: 'results', component: ResultsComponent },
    { path: 'photo', component: PhotoComponent },
    { path: 'partners', component: PartnersComponent },
    { path: 'contacts', component: ContactsComponent},
    { path: ':name', component: StageComponent }, // if no child routes found then display default
    ]}
];

Or you can delete this line and if user write anything else that you have in children array then redirect it to 404 page .
For more info please read docs on Angular https://angular.io/guide/router they have really good explanation of how things works in angular.
```